# Array isn't filled with object in Javascript

Tags: reactjs

So after the content is loaded in the website I'm trying to call a function to fill [fields] (State) with the events but something Isn't working.

Here is what I mean:

```js
const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (orders.orders !== null && orders.isLoading !== true)
      orders.orders.map((order) =>
        setEvents([
          ...events,
          {
            title: `Meeting with ${order.customer.firstName}`,
            date: `${order.appointment}`,
          },
        ])
      );
    setLoading(false);
  }, [orders]);
```

So when I console log the events, I get `[]` (empty), but if i console.log the object it works.

Comment: Console doesnot needs re render so it works in console

Comment: events is const and initially [], so you call setEvents([...[], {new event}]) for each order, which doesn't look right; use the result of orders.map instead. but that would result in one element in events not zero.

Comment: try doing setEVents(oldEvents => [
          ...oldEvents,
          {
            title: `Meeting with ${order.customer.firstName}`,
            date: `${order.appointment}`,
          },
        ])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the code but looks like your `useEffect` has a missing dependency of `events`. Since you are also updating `events` with `setEvents`, you should update with

```
setEvents(prev=>[
  ...prev,
   {
     title: `Meeting with ${order.customer.firstName}`,
     date: `${order.appointment}`,
    }
])
```

to avoid an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are directly updating state so it is shown in console but in react rerender should be done to update state so pass parameter for setEvents and spread parameter but not directly events because you cannot directly update state.

```
const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (orders.orders !== null && orders.isLoading !== true)
          orders.orders.map((order) =>
            setEvents(prev => [
              ...prev,
              {
                title: `Meeting with ${order.customer.firstName}`,
                date: `${order.appointment}`,
              },
            ])
          );
        setLoading(false);
      }, [orders]);
```